# XMLDatasource - only show first two entrys

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a little XML Problem. I have a XML with for example 7 entrys. But i only want to show the first two entrys.

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlDSName" DataFile="test.xml"> XPath="Direx/Person" runat="server" />


<asp:ListView ID="DirexUserName" DataSourceID="xmlDSName" ItemPlaceholderID="PlcaID" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <%# XPath("GivenName")%>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Is there maybe an option, where I can say, how much entrys it should load?

Thank you very much for your help!

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using position?

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlDSName" DataFile="test.xml" XPath="Direx/Person[position()<3]" runat="server"/>
```